# Simple schema is accepting null values in required fields

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

Simple Schema is accepting and inserting `null` into required fields. Shouldn't it error? Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here. 
I'm using these packages.

- mdg:validated-method
- mdg:validation-error
- simpl-schema

`Simple Schema`

```
export const ProfileCandidate = new Mongo.Collection('profileCandidate');

const profileCandidate = new SimpleSchema({
  name: Object,
    'name.first': String,
    'name.last': String,
  }
});
```

`Method Call`

```
var data = {
  'name.first': this.state.firstName,
  'name.last': this.state.lastName,
};

insertProfileCandidate.call(data, (err, res) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log("err: ", err);
  }
});
```

`ValidateMethod`

```
export const insertProfileCandidate = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'profileCandidate.insert',

  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    'name.first': { type: String, min: 1 },
    'name.last': { type: String, min: 1 },
  }).validator({ clean: true }),

  run(data) {
    ProfileCandidate.insert({
      name: {
        first: data['name.first'],
        last: data['name.last'],
      }
    }, (error, result) => {
      if (error) throw new Meteor.Error('400', error.invalidKeys);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it appears as though I needed to also install `collection2-core`